# Create pop ups using Mkdocs material Theme

Tags: markdown, mkdocs-material

I am using Mkdocs material in markdown to create a document for the product. My requirement is to add a pop that appears everytime the user opens my website. The user can cancel if required. The pop up will have certain options that  can choose and this redirect to a URL. It needs to look something like this.

[image: pop up for website]

Any ideas how I can do it?

Comment: Material for MkDocs does not provide popups, so you would need to write the necessary code yourself. The Insider edition, however, has a [privacy plugin](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/plugins/privacy) that contains functionality to create a modal dialogue that is used for GDPR compliance, getting consent from people for data processing. If what you want to do is similar enough then perhaps you could repurpose this?